# Как создать одномерный массив, в котором половина рандомных элементов будут положительными, а вторая - отрицательными?

Tags: java

Задание из костина

> Программа должна создать массив из 12 случайных целых чисел из отрезка [-10;10] таким образом, чтобы отрицательных и положительных элементов там было поровну и не было нулей. При этом порядок следования элементов должен быть случаен (т. е. не подходит вариант, когда в массиве постоянно выпадает сначала 6 положительных, а потом 6 отрицательных чисел или же когда элементы постоянно чередуются через один и пр.). Вывести полученный массив на экран.

Попытался сначала заполнить, потом откинуть нули, вроде получилось, а вот с знаками не понятно, поменять знаки я понимаю как, но как половину массива поменять вообще не могу понять.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] m = new int[12];
    for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++){
        m[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*21-10);
        if(m[i]==0){
            m[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*21-10);}
        for(i=0;i<m.length/2;i++){
            if(m[i]==Math.abs(m[i])){
                m[i] = m[i] * -1;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(m[i] + "  ");
}}}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Возможно не самый простой для понимания, но тоже рабочий вариант:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] m = new int[12];
        int posCnt = 0;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++) {
            m[i] = rnd.nextInt(10) + 1;
            if(posCnt == m.length/2) {
                m[i] = -m[i];
            }
            else if((m.length - i) > (m.length/2 - posCnt)) {
              int sgn = rnd.nextInt(2);
              m[i] = m[i] * (int)Math.pow(-1, sgn);
              posCnt += -sgn + 1;
            }
            System.out.print(m[i] + "  ");
        }
    }
}
```

По поводу Вашего вопроса, Вы как-то все запутали вложенным циклом. Если хотите реализовать подобную логику, то во вложенном цикле вводите вторую переменную, например `for(int j=0;j<m.length/2;j++)`

Плюс еще пару комментариев по Вашему коду:

```
m[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*21-10);
```

Тут Вы пытаетесь сделать рандомное число от 0 до 21 и далее вычитаете 10. Т.е. реально Вы можете получить тут 11, что не удовлетворяет условиям.

```
if(m[i]==0){ m[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*21-10);}
```

Тут если выпал 0, то вы повторяете рандомизацию. Но рандом не запрещает возможности выпадания нуля 2 раза. Т.е. опять же условие может быть не соблюдено.

```
for(i=0;i<m.length/2;i++){
    if(m[i]==Math.abs(m[i])){
        m[i] = m[i] * -1;
    }
}
```

Даже если не брать во внимание повторное использование переменной i, что уже само по себе не верно, то тут я как минимум не вижу никакого подсчета, т.е. Вы не гарантируете того, что будет поровну положительных и отрицательных чисел.

Comment: Ваша версия рабочая, спс. Объясните пож. по работе вот эти строки "int sgn = rnd.nextInt(2);
              m[i] = m[i] * (int)Math.pow(-1, sgn);
              posCnt += -sgn + 1;"

Comment: зачем sgn присваивать рандомное значение ? зачем дальше возведение в степень ?)) извините за тупняк с моей стороны, хочется разобраться)

Comment: @Ustin сразу скажу внес небольшую корректировку: вначале цикла должно быть `m[i] = rnd.nextInt(10) + 1;`, т.е. 10 включительно по условию.
Теперь по поводу вопроса. `rnd.NextInt(2)` генерирует числа в диапозоне [0,2), т.е. 2 уже не входит. Соответственно sgn определяет рандомный знак числа и принимает значение 0 или 1. `Math.pow(-1, sgn)` возводит -1 в степень. Т.е. имеем либо (-1)^0 = 1, либо (-1)^1 = -1. Ну и дальше учитывая, что sgn=1 - отрицательный, а sgn=0 - положительный, считаем количетсво положительных `posCnt += -sgn + 1`. Надеюсь, не слишком запутанно объяснил, если что уточняйте =)

Comment: В целом, все это сделано для того, чтобы соблюсти условие "При этом порядок следования элементов должен быть случаен"

Answer (score 1):

В качестве идеи могу предложить следующий код, написанный на C#. Вы можете переписать его на Java.

```
const int N = 12;
int[] a = new int[N];

Random rnd = new Random();
int positive = 0;
int negative = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    int value;
    do
    {
        value = rnd.Next(-10, 10);
    } while (value == 0 ||
              (value < 0 && negative == (N + 1) / 2) ||
              (value > 0 && positive == (N + 1) / 2));

    if ( value < 0 ) ++negative;
    else ++positive;

    a[i] = value;
}

foreach (int x in a) Console.Write("{0} ", x);
Console.WriteLine();
```

Я думаю, что идею кода не трудно понять.

Вывод данного фрагмента кода может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
2 4 7 -1 1 -1 -3 6 -10 3 -3 -7
```

Центральное место в коде занимает данный `while` цикл

```
    do
    {
        value = rnd.Next(-10, 10);
    } while (value == 0 ||
              (value < 0 && negative == (N + 1) / 2) ||
              (value > 0 && positive == (N + 1) / 2));
```

Он генерирует случайное число отличное от нуля и либо отрицательное либо положительное с учетом того, сгенерированы ли уже все положительные или отрицательные числа из заданного лимита.

Для подсчета уже сгенерированных отрицательных и положительных случайных значений вам нужно ввести счетчики, как, например

```
int positive = 0;
int negative = 0;
```

Что касается вашего кода, то имейте в виду, что одну и ту же переменную `i` вы используете в двух циклах

```
for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++){
    //...
    for(i=0;i<m.length/2;i++){
        //...
        }
    }
```

в результате чего внешний цикл будет работать не так, как вы предполагаете.

То есть вас внешний цикл из-за этого будет бесконечным, потому что следующая итерация всегда начинается с `i` равным `m.length/2`

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] m = new int[12];
  int neg=0, pos=0;
  for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++){
   do{
    
   m[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*21-10);
   }while( m[i] ==0 || neg>m.length/2 || pos > m.length/2 );
  if(m[i]>0){pos++;}
  else{neg++;}
   System.out.print(m[i] + "  ");
   
  }
  System.out.println();
  System.out.print(pos + "  " + neg);
 }
}
сваял на основе вашего. иногда выполняет( все правильно - спасибо), а иногда подвисает и подгружает комп. Толи зацикливает, толи как это называется :) Осталось разобраться из-за чего подвисон.

Comment: Для меня лично дико что я сначала проверяю позитивную\негативную переменную, а потом уже инкрементирую. Но работает же :))

Comment: @Ustin Не совсем понял, что здесь "дико"?

Comment: @Ustin Имейте в виду, что ваше условие в цикле while    while( m[i] ==0 || neg>m.length/2 || pos > m.length/2 ) отличается от моего и не является верным.